# Проблема с заменой данных xml excel php

Tags: php, excel

Подскажите пожалуйста почему код не рабочий. Суть в том чтобы распаковывать `xlsx`, менять в нем значение ячейки, и запаковывать обратно. У меня не меняются данные, не сохраняются изменения в `sharedStrings.xml`.
Код `sharedStrings.xml`

```xml
    <sst xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main" count="2" uniqueCount="2">
      <si>
        <t>Name</t>
      </si>
      <si>
        <t>LastName</t>
      </si>
    </sst>
```

После работы скрипта

```xml
    <worksheet xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main" 
               xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships">
      <sheetPr codeName="Лист1"/>
      <dimension ref="B2:C2"/>
      <sheetViews>
        <sheetView tabSelected="1" workbookViewId="0">
          <selection activeCell="C2" sqref="C2"/>
        </sheetView>
      </sheetViews>
      <sheetFormatPr defaultRowHeight="15"/>
      <sheetData>
        <row r="2" spans="2:3">
          <c r="B2" t="s">
            <v>0</v>
          </c>
          <c r="C2" t="s">
            <v>1</v>
          </c>
        </row>
      </sheetData>
      <pageMargins left="0.7" right="0.7" top="0.75" bottom="0.75" header="0.3" footer="0.3"/>
    </worksheet>
```

Сам код скрипта

```php
    <?php
    require_once('pclzip.lib.php');
    $archive = new PclZip('1.xlsx');

    if ($archive->extract() == 0) {
        die("Error : ".$archive->errorInfo(true));
    }
    
    $file=file_get_contents('xl/sharedStrings.xml');
    $xml = (array)simplexml_load_string($file);
    $sst = array();
    foreach ($xml['si'] as $item=>$val) $sst[] = (string)$val->t;
    
    $file = file_get_contents('xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml');
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($file);
    $data1 = array();

    foreach ($xml->sheetData->row as $row){
        $currow = array();
        foreach ($row->c as $c){
            $value = (string)$c->v;
            $attrs = $c->attributes();
            
            if ($attrs['t'] == 's'){
                $currow[] = $sst[$value];
            }
            else{
                $currow[] = $value;
            }
        }
        $data1[] = $currow;
    }
    
    $line = $data1;
    
    $line[0][0] = 'Saymon';
    $line[0][1] = ' Black';
    
    $xml->asXML('xl/sharedStrings.xml');
    
    $archive = new PclZip('2.xlsx');
    
    $result = $archive->create('xl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels,xl/theme/theme1.xml,xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml,xl/sharedStrings.xml,xl/styles.xml,xl/workbook.xml,docProps/app.xml,docProps/core.xml,_rels/,[Content_Types].xml');
    
    ?>
```

Comment: а библиотеки для работы с экселем (какой-нибудь [tag:phpexcel]) вы принципиально не хотите использовать?